# Timeout error for tlsmail for sending mail via devise and action_mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am currently trying to deploy an application to a 65 bit centos vm, with the following specs:

```
rvm 1.13.8
ruby 1.9.3p194
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips
```

I am using Apache, Capistrano, and Phusion passenger

My /config/environments/production.rb has the following lines

```
Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL:SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => MY URL }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :enable_starttls_auto => true,
   address: "smtp.gmail.com",
   port: 587,
   domain: "gmail.com",
   authentication: "plain",
   user_name: "MyGMAILEMAIL@gmail.com",
   password: ENV["GMAIL_PASS"]

}
```

My development environments uses the exact same settings, with changed host set to my gloabl IP.

for good measure, my development stats (32bit ubuntu VM):
    rvm 1.25.19
    ruby 1.9.3p545
    OpenSSL 1.0.0e

My development environment works great at sending emails, but this is what I get when read my /var/log/httpd/error_log file

```
App 4738 stdout: Started POST "/users" for MY IP at 2014-03-14 21:11:29+0300

App 4738 stdout: Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML

App 4738 stdout:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"9CGdegNfbYkPljo1Rx/VLngfrhCLlw9IpKfPwm/uCuo=", "user"=>{"email"=>"MY EMAIL", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Signup"}

App 4676 stderr: [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.

App 4676 stderr:

App 4738 stdout:   Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (1.1ms)

App 4738 stdout:

App 4738 stdout: Sent mail to my EMAIL (30018.6ms)

App 4738 stdout: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31220ms

App 4738 stdout:

App 4738 stdout: Timeout::Error (execution expired):

App 4738 stdout:   tlsmail (0.0.1) lib/net/smtp.rb:454:in `initialize'

App 4738 stdout:   tlsmail (0.0.1) lib/net/smtp.rb:454:in `open'

App 4738 stdout:   tlsmail (0.0.1) lib/net/smtp.rb:454:in `block in do_start'

App 4738 stdout:   tlsmail (0.0.1) lib/net/smtp.rb:454:in `do_start'

App 4738 stdout:   tlsmail (0.0.1) lib/net/smtp.rb:440:in `start'

App 4738 stdout:   mail (2.5.4) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'

App 4738 stdout:   mail (2.5.4) lib/mail/message.rb:2129:in `do_delivery'

App 4738 stdout:   mail (2.5.4) lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `block in deliver'

App 4738 stdout:   actionmailer (4.0.2) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:456:in `block in deliver_mail'
```

Something I have noticed, when I run

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

on my development VM: I get

```
trying 74.125.196.108
connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com
```

and my production VM: i get

```
trying 74.125.196.108
```

and it hangs there, no confirmation, just hangs there and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out. I will put this here if anyone has any similar problems

run ping smtp.gmail.com and find the IP address

then on your server run csf -a {the IP address}

that should allow your application to hit the gmail smtp server